# Python: How to output data with "" into CSV?

Tags: python, csv

I would like to output data with "" into CSV file.
By executing this code, I expected that all values in each column in the generated csv were double quoted however weren't.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import numpy

df = pd.DataFrame([{'data1': 'A', 'data2': "B", 'data3': "C", 'data4': "D", 'data5': "E", 'data6': "F"}])
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

Expected result

`"data1", "data2", "data3", "data4", "data5", "data6"
"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"`

Actual result

`data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6
A, B, C, D, E, F`

I'm operating with 
`python 3.8.0`
`pandas 0.25.3`
`numpy 1.17.4`

Thank you

Comment: I tried your code with python 3.7.1,  pandas0.25.3, numpy 1.17.4 and it export the file what you expected. I don't see any problem

Comment: I downgrade python, pandas, numpy but still I could not get expected result (i.e. opening output.csv to find 
data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6
A, B, C, D, E, F

Answer (score 1):

You have to quote on single `'` each value of your dict for the desired result :
`df = pd.DataFrame([{'data1': '"A"', 'data2': '"B"', 'data3': '"C"', 'data4': '"D"', 'data5': '"E"', 'data6': '"F"'}])`

Comment: No. What I want to do is that read non-double-quoted value and output with double-quote. In my understanding all values(str, float, int) should be double quoted in output since I am writing quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL in to_csv.